# How can regular people navigate through the different seas in One Piece?

Tags: one-piece

The way I understand the One Piece world, the North Blue, the South Blue, the East Blue and the West Blue are either separated by the Red Line or the Grand Line, the Grand Line itself being separated by those Blues by the Calm Belt.

In the story, we have met a number of people coming from different areas of the world to another area that I cannot even foresee how they did.

For Marines and World Government folks, they have Paddle Ships coated with Seastone that allows them to navigate through Calm Belt, without triggering Sea Kings (gigantic sea creatures)

Shanks, Buggy, Zeff, Mihawk, those guys definitely already went in the Grand Line prior to the start of the adventures of the Strawhats

Another weird case would be Sanji, born in the North Blue, and somehow ended in East Blue with Zeff aboard the Baratie before joining the Strawhats (the way he went from North Blue to East Blue may have been explained already but I just don't remember - I assume he was still in North Blue when encountering Zeff's crew)

Even during the Baratie arc, Don Krieg said his fleet got owned right after entering the Grand Line (through Reverse Mountain I assume - never was confirmed), and he somehow made his way out of the Grand Line

My main question here is, apart from Marines, how can one sail from one sea to another (for example, from North Blue to East Blue, from North Blue to West Blue), or out of Grand Line?

If it hasn't been explained in universe yet, but if anyone has already made a very plausible theory on that matter, a link to the theory can be accepted. If Oda already explained it via an SBS, I could accept the SBS question and answer

Additional info:

- Reverse Mountain has four UPCURRENTS that merge into the only current leading to Paradise (the first part of the Grand Line), so using it to travel between the blues is very unlikely
- IIRC, to go from Paradise (the first part of the Grand Line) into New World (the second part of the Grand Line), and maybe the other way around, regulars can ask for a permit to go over the Red Line at WG HQ, pirates have to go through Fishman Island under the seas
- Last time I read One Piece was during Kozuki Oden's flashback, during Wano arc, so in-universe information up to that point is non-spoilery for me (I wouldn't know for other people who would read this question though)

Comment: As far as I know, people dont. It's rare for people to switch seas unless they've gone to the grand line. Thats why Luffy and the other Worst Gen pirates never encountered or even heard of each other before the Grand Line because they were nowhere near one another. As for Sanji, it was shown in Whole Cake Island why he moved seas but I'll avoid spoilers because I dont know if you're fully caught up.

Comment: @knightwatch I stopped reading for a while in the middle of Wano so I'm fine on that, memory's still hazy though, don't remember if he just fled on the ship attacked by Zeff

Comment: When Sanji was a boy, Germa 66 crossed the Red Line with their snail ships from the North Blue to the East Blue. After that he wound up on the ship Zeff attacked.

Comment: that explains it for Sanji then, got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no official answer as of this time about how average people could move between Seas, or even how to leave the Grand Line, there are a few ways that this could be possible.

**Calm Belt**

The average ship cannot cross the Calm Belt without being destroyed by Sea Beasts, it is possible for ships equipped with sea stone like Marine ships, or for those strong enough to face the Sea Beasts head on such as Rayleigh. This is also likely how Mihawk got to the East Blue.

That being said this is not something regular people could ever attempt.

**Crossing over the Red Line**

We know you can cross from Paradise to the New World in the Grand Line by going over Marijoa for a fee. It has never been confirmed but it is possible there could be other points like this on the Red Line for ships, (most likely merchant ships or Marine vessels) could cross over.

We see Germa 66 have the ability to cross the Red Line, but this is an extremely rare ability that no others are shown having.

**Going under the Red Line**

Most pirates enter the New World through Fishman Island by going under the Red Line. Like with going over, it has never been stated if other points exist but it is possible there are other holes in the Red Line which could be entered if the ships were coated.

**In Summary**

There are several ways to cross between seas, but most take an excessive amount of skill, strength or money. So I believe the most likely way average people cross between seas is...

They dont. Most people in our world rarely go outside their country or continent. It's not strange to think that in the One Piece world, only a few have ever been to more than one sea. Even Luffy and most of his crew have only ever lived in the East Blue.

Comment: do we know how Don Krieg left the Grand Line after his encounter with Mihawk?

Comment: @prout I haven’t seen a confirmed answer anywhere but most people believe he went through the calm belt as well.

Answer (score 0):

This hasn't directly been addressed during the series or even in SBS segments. However we can paint a picture based on other facts that we've heard. **To provide an answer up front, I would say most regular people do not leave their islands even within the seas, much less to a different sea.**

This answer contains examples from various points in the series, but they're vague enough that I wouldn't consider them to be a problem.

We encounter various [types of ships](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Ship#Ships_by_Status) in the series, the most relevant ones being:

1. Pirate ships
2. Marine and World Government ships
3. Merchant ships

With piracy being such a common problem, it would be dangerous for any ships to sail the seas without adequate protection. Since the pirates are everywhere, even sailing within a sea and not crossing the Calm Belt / entering the Grand Line carries this risk. The two categories of people who directly accept this risk and still sail are pirates and bounty hunters (who haven't appeared much in the series).

People with influence such as the royalty of a particular island might be able to get a ride on Marine / World Government ships. This is what happened when everyone gathered for the Levely (or Reverie), they were provided escorts and did not travel on their own. We also see proof of the escort being necessary as pirates attack one of the ships.

Merchant ships have never been shown and only been mentioned a couple of times. The wiki notes that Mont Blanc Noland and Brook both purchased items from such ships. We also know that legal trade has to be a thing in One Piece due to two famous examples:

1. Pappag, the starfish from Fishman Island, created a fashion label known as [Criminal](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Criminal) that is said to be popular throughout the world.
2. Wapol's invention of a new alloy known as [Wapometal](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Wapometal) turned him into a wealthy CEO at the helm of a toy company. He was even granted a new kingdom as a reward.

Depending on how abundant they turn out to be in the future of the series, these Merchant ships might be the best way to transport people and goods across seas. I guess the cruise ship Sanji was on (The Orbit) might fall under this category too.

There is also a confirmed [Underworld](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Underworld) that has shady dealings and smuggling outside the World Government's control. According to the wiki, they seem to be focused in the New World, with some appearances in North Blue and West Blue.

The most common way for everyone else who is desperate to leave an island is to **stowaway**. It doesn't really matter on whose ship you end up doing this, and we've seen plenty of examples:

1. Luffy hid aboard Vice Admiral Momonga's ship to get to Impel Down from Amazon Lily.
2. Robin (not a member of the crew at that point) sneaks aboard the Going Merry before the crew leaves Arabasta.
3. Caribou has been stowed away in a barrel on the Thousand Sunny at least once, maybe twice.
4. Law escaped his hometown by pretending to be a dead body on a ship carrying them.

Comment: I agree with your main point that people likely dont leave their home island/sea but I dont see how merchant ships or being a stowaway solves the problem of how a regular person could cross the sea. Those are going to be pretty rare occasions and not something the average person would do.

Comment: I didn't claim that it solves the problem. I just said desperate enough people might use those options (and have done so in the past). That's why the part in bold is up at the top saying most people don't do it. IF merchant ships become a thing - which we have no confirmation about currently - then it makes it much simpler for those with money to get on a cruise. However so far in the series, we haven't actually seen many examples, definitely none that cross between seas.

Comment: do we know how Don Krieg left the Grand Line after his encounter with Mihawk?